# Alter Object So That Spec Is Organized?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm using PL/SQL and I'd like to alter a type by adding an attribute. I need to alter as there are table dependencies that prevent replacing. When I use the following code.

```
create or replace type example_type as object
(
  num_var number
);

alter type example_type add attribute (varchar2_var varchar2(10));
```

It creates a spec with that exact code.

Is there a way to make it so that the spec looks like

```
create or replace type example_type as object
(
  num_var number,
  varchar2_var varchar2(10)
);
```

Instead?

Comment: Do you mean when you get the `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` for the type?

Comment: I'm using PL/SQL Developer, when I right click and say "View Spec & Body" it returns the statements used above. If possible I'd essentially like to alter the type by writing directly into the spec's body.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. In 10g you can reset the type and that apparently changes the definition; in 11g that doesn't seem to happen (you still have two statements in `user_type_versions`). And you wouldn't be able to do it with table dependencies anyway, I think.

Comment: Not sure but can you just try compiling the `body` and `spec` by using  : `ALTER TYPE example_type COMPILE;` and see if there is any change in how your metadata looks.

Comment: @MahendarMahi - therwasn't when I tried that (11.2.0.4).